# How to filter the find method for a field on its relations?

Tags: nest, typeorm

The structure of my application is that I have:

- Contacts
- Groups
- Lanes (belong to groups)
- GroupContacts (join table to assign a contact to a group and assign a lane)

My entities are:

lane.entity.ts

```
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  Unique,
  OneToMany,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Group } from './group.entity';
import { GroupContact } from './groupcontact.entity';

@Entity('lanes')
@Unique('UQ_NAMES', ['group', 'name'])
export class Lane {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  sequence: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false, default: 30 })
  updateFrequencyDays: number;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
    type: 'timestamp',
  })
  createdAt: Date;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => Group,
    group => group.lanes,
  )
  group: Group;

  @OneToMany(
    type => GroupContact,
    groupcontact => groupcontact.lane,
  )
  groupContacts: GroupContact[];
}
```

groupcontact.entity.ts

```
import { Contact } from '../contacts/contact.entity';
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn, ManyToOne, JoinColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Group } from './group.entity';
import { Lane } from './lane.entity';

@Entity('groups_contacts')
export class GroupContact {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  groupId: number;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  contactId: number;

  @Column()
  laneId: number;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
    type: 'timestamp',
  })
  createdAt: Date;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => Group,
    group => group.contactConnection,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'groupId' })
  group: Group;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => Contact,
    contact => contact.groupConnection,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'contactId' })
  contact: Contact;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => Lane,
    lane => lane.groupContacts,
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'laneId' })
  lane: Lane;
}
```

contact.entity.ts

```
import { Group } from 'src/groups/group.entity';
import { GroupContact } from '../groups/groupcontact.entity';
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  OneToMany,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity('contacts')
export class Contact {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column()
  public firstName: string;

  @Column()
  public lastName: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
    type: 'timestamp',
  })
  public createdAt: Date;

  @OneToMany(
    type => GroupContact,
    gc => gc.contact,
  )
  groupConnection: GroupContact[];
}
```

What I am trying to do is that I am trying to return all contacts that belong to a particular group. But when returning those contacts, I'd also like to return the groupConnection object.

Here is the code I am using:

```
   async getContacts(groupId) {
    const group = await this.findOneByIdOrThrow(groupId);
    const contacts = await this.contactRepository.find({
      //where: { groupConnection: { groupId: groupId } },
      relations: ['groupConnection'],
    });

    return contacts;
  }
```

So far, am I able to return what I wanted, which is a list of contacts together with their relations. But I have not found a way to filter those results to retrieve only the ones that belong to a particular groupId.

Where clause commented.

How do I filter for that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by using QueryBuilder

```
 const contacts = await this.contactRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('contacts')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('contacts.groupConnection', 'groupConnection')
      .where('groupConnection.groupId = :groupId', { groupId })
      .getMany();
```